# How do I transform first-differenced impulse response functions back into levels?

Tags: vector-autoregression, logarithm, impulse-response, differencing

I am estimating a structural VAR where all my variables are I(1). I took the log differences of each variable and generated the impulse response functions. Is there a way to convert the impulse response functions back to levels?